# Speeding up WordPress query when searching for value in `meta_value`

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Any tips on how I can speed up a WordPress query that searches for data in the `meta_value` in the `postmeta` table?

`postmeta` table contains just under 5 million records. A custom WP plug-in takes too long to process the data. I traced which query actually slows down and found this. The query is one of over 60 that is ran when `get_posts` is ran, bur this one takes 99% of the processing time.

```
SELECT wp_wordpress_posts.* FROM wp_wordpress_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_wordpress_postmeta ON (wp_wordpress_posts.ID = wp_wordpress_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_wordpress_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_wordpress_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND wp_wordpress_posts.post_type = 'my_booking' 
AND (wp_wordpress_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
AND ( (wp_wordpress_postmeta.meta_key = '_rooms' AND CAST(wp_wordpress_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '236742')
AND  (mt1.meta_key = '_bookingDate' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = '2018-09-18') ) 
GROUP BY wp_wordpress_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_wordpress_posts.post_date DESC
```

I started testing a simplified version

```
SELECT wp_wordpress_postmeta.* FROM wp_wordpress_postmeta  
WHERE meta_key = '_rooms' AND CAST(meta_value AS CHAR) = '236742'
```

This query takes about a second to process. I realized that whoever wrote the plugin, stores searchable data in the `meta_value` field that is set to `LONGTEXT` so it can not be indexed. Since the searchable data is pretty short, I added shortened index to the `meta_key` and `meta_value`

ALTER TABLE `wp_wordpress_postmeta` ADD key(meta_key(100), meta_value(100))

I ran the short query and it improved the speed, making the query run 5 times faster. I tried the long query again, it it made no improvements to it. I tried running another query from the long one

```
SELECT wp_wordpress_postmeta.* FROM wp_wordpress_postmeta  
WHERE meta_key = '_bookingDate' AND CAST(meta_value AS CHAR) = '2018-09-18'
```

This query takes about a second to process. Why does this query sees no improvement from the shortened index like the first one? How can I fix that?

Comment: It looks like you're doing the same inner join twice, but giving the alias `mt1` in the second one. Is there a reason for that? That could partly be why it's slow since it'd doubling up on data. What is the `explain` output?

Comment: @Anch0rman This query is generated by the WordPress itself. I'm not sure why it is creating an alias. Still, if I simply run `SELECT wp_wordpress_postmeta.* FROM wp_wordpress_postmeta  
WHERE meta_key = '_bookingDate' AND CAST(meta_value AS CHAR) = '2018-09-18'` It runs slower than the first short query, even though this query returns less results.